# Find Nodes NOT MATCHed by a Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I run a Cypher query and update labels of the nodes matching a certain criteria. I also want to update nodes that do not pass that criteria in the same query, before I update the matched ones. Is there a construct in Cypher that can help me achieve this?

Here is a concrete formulation. I have a pool of labels from which I choose and assign to nodes. When I run a certain query, I assign one of those labels, `l`, to the nodes returned under the conditions specified by `WHERE` clause in the query. However, `l` could have been assigned to other nodes previously, and I want to rid all those nodes of `l` which are not the result of this query.

The conditions in `WHERE` clause could be arbitrary; hence simple negation would probably not work. An example code is as follows:

```
MATCH (v)
WHERE <some set of conditions>
// here I want to remove 'l' from the nodes
// not satisfied by the above condition
SET v:l
```

I have solved this problem by using a temporary label through this process:

1. Assign `x` to `v`.
2. Remove `l` from all nodes.
3. Assign `l` to all nodes containing `x`.
4. Removing `x` from all nodes.

Is there a better way to achieve this in Cypher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like one reasonable solution:

```
MATCH (v)
WITH REDUCE(s = {a:[], d:[]}, x IN COLLECT(v) |
  CASE
    WHEN <some set of conditions> AND NOT('l' IN LABELS(x)) THEN {a: s.a+x, d: s.d}
    WHEN 'l' IN LABELS(x) THEN {a: s.a, d: s.d+x}
  END) AS actions
FOREACH (a IN actions.a | SET a:l)
FOREACH (d IN actions.d | REMOVE d:l)
```

The above query tests every node, and remembers in the `actions.a` list the nodes that need the `l` label but do not yet have it, and in the `actions.d` list the nodes that have the label but should not. Then it performs the appropriate action for each list, without updating any nodes that are already OK.

Comment: An `ELSE` clause would be required in case none of the 2 scenarios are executed.

Comment: @SRA `ELSE` is not required. If neither scenario applies, then `actions` will be `NULL` and the `FOREACH` clauses will do nothing in that case.

Comment: That is true as a general rule. In this case, when neither condition matches for any `v`, `null` is returned and stored in the map `s`. `FOREACH` will then do nothing which is not desirable here. Tested with Neo4j 3.4.4.

Comment: I guess I do not understand your exact use case, then. But at least you seem to understand the gist, which is probably good enough.